# Why is the following flexbox on the left rather than the top?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is my flexbox setup:

```
section[_v-f4d9afa6] { // parent
  display: flex;
}

article[_v-e514def2] { // child
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 50%;
}

article header[_v-e514def2] { // child of child
  background-color: #484a47;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

article section[_v-e514def2] { // child of child 2
  margin: 10px;
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I get this:

[image]

What should I change so the dark gray child is on the top? (Like an OS window)?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qjog7tvu/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `flex-direction: column;` for `article[_v-e514def2]`

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is remove `display: flex` from article and just let it default as article and section are block element so header will arrange itself to top of section.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qjog7tvu/3/)